# Tag wikis in two languages without paragraphs?

Tags: feature-request

It seems that I cannot make paragraphs in the excerpt of a tag wiki which is a problem because this should be both in English and German.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Given that we plan to have tag names in English, I would say it would make most sense to have the excerpt in English as well. The full wiki page then can contain a description in both languages.